# how to recognize phone numbers in web page?

Tags: java, php, web

How to recognize phone numbers in web page?

How skype click to call is working. 
I want build an application for detect phone number in web page. How it is possible like skype click to call?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='tel:']")`

Comment: Please use SkypeDeveloper tag only for questions when developing using Skype Developer Platform APIs and components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression to find all the phone numbers in your input paragraph and then replace them with surrounding anchor tags like `<a href="tel: <phonenumber>"><phonenumber></a>`

Your code should be somewhat like this:

**Output**

```
INPUT PARAGRAPH                                                                                                                                                                 
-----------                                                                                                                                                                     
<p>Lets say that this is a sample paragraph with one phone number like 800-965-2321 
and another phone number let's say 70923-23124</p>                                          
-----------                                                                                                                                                                     

OUTPUT PARAGRAPH                                                                                                                                                                
-----------                                                                                                                                                                     
<p>Lets say that this is a sample paragraph with one phone number like <a href="tel: 800-965-2321">800-965-2321</a>    
and another phone number let's say <a href="te: 70923-23124">70923-23124</a></p>                                                                                                                                                       
-----------
```

**Java Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// our main class becomes a file but the main method is still found
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String htmlParagraph = "<p>Lets say that this is a sample paragraph with one phone number like 800-965-2321 and another phone number let's say 70923-23124</p>";
    System.out.println("INPUT PARAGRAPH\n-----------\n"+htmlParagraph+"\n-----------\n");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\d -]{8,13})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlParagraph); 
    htmlParagraph = m.replaceAll(" <a href=\"tel:$1\">$1</a> ");
    System.out.println("OUTPUT PARAGRAPH\n-----------\n"+htmlParagraph+"\n-----------\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: How it possible in PHP?